# Community Ads not being displayed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community, advertising

According to [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19615) statement:

> **September update:** Community Ads are now live network-wide. All ads with a score of 6 or higher, or with a score of 4 or higher and no downvotes will be displayed (except for any that have a note from the CM Team explaining why it wasn't selected).

Community Ads are live.

But I can see no Community Ads in https://askubuntu.com. I have also asked fellow users about this, and they too cannot see the ads.

All I could see were these:

[image: Screenshot of one of the ads]

[image: Screenshot of one of the ads]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just double checked the reporting tools used for the Community Ads, and can confirm the ads submitted in the initiative on this site are being displayed around 200~300 times a day each.

You may not see these ads all that frequently because they are being run in rotation with hundreds of other ad campaigns, and which ad you see is dependent on a large amount of factors, such as:

- Your geographical location (country);
- Which campaigns you’ve seen previously on the network;
- The tags of the content you are visiting;
- Time of day, day of week, etc.;
- How the campaigns are pacing (i.e. forecasted to hit their target).